# Tika Docx Scanning for 2 MB file (Pure text docx file) taking more than 30 seconds

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, apache-tika, tika-server

I am using tika 2.6.x with java opts as XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=200M -Xss512K -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64M for below code. It seems that processing time is very high(around a minute) for a pure text containing docx file of size more than equals to 2 MB. Same code logic is working very efficient for 2 MB csv, pptx and other files and sending the response in less than 5seconds. Any more configuration needed? please suggest, thanks.

```
Parser pasrer=new AutoDetectParser()
BufferWriter=Files.newBufferedWriter("MyFile")
Handler handler=new BodyContentHandler(BufferWriter)
//some code logic for embdedded image
context.set(classOf[EmbeddedDocumentExtractor], imageChecker)
parse(TikaInputStreamObj, handler, Metadata, context)
```

Comment: Updating the reason behind this latency:- Files like docx, pptx are compressed formats, if we are creating a pure text file of lets say 2 MB for docx, its actual size can be identified via checking the byte Array and that coming as very large in length. So, a 2 MB text file and 2 MB docx file having only text cant be comparable to validate the response time.